# The Download Preview window in the Dock - how to change sequence

Tags: dock

Since 10.11, the order of items in the Downloads folder in the Dock has changed to alphabetic. Is it possible to change it to show by date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Control+click on the folder on the dock, and select `Sort by Date Added`.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, no problem (: